# MySQL - Zero count issue

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to write a query to show zero counts for a user.

```
SELECT `profiles`.scanner_id, IFNULL(COUNT(attendance_data.user_id),0) AS AbsentHr  
FROM `profiles`
INNER JOIN attendance_data ON attendance_data.dwEnrollNumber=`profiles`.scanner_id
WHERE attendance_data.OutTime='Absent' AND attendance_data.Approved<>1 AND dwEnrollNumber=5059
```

Result is the count shows `zero` but the scanner id is `null`.

I want the scanner id to show `5059`. Have tried this query with subqueries, left joins but no success thus far.

How can i do this ?

I tried this as well

SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(attendance_data.user_id), 0) AS AbsentHr , `profiles`.user_id
FROM `profiles`
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance_data ON `profiles`.user_id=attendance_data.user_id
WHERE attendance_data.OutTime='Absent' AND attendance_data.Approved=0 
GROUP BY `profiles`.user_id

This bring me back 73 records all with their counts. I have 80 though that have a zero count and they are missing. Any ideas.

Comment: Where's your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: When I added a Group By (`profiles`.scanner_id) I do not even get a record back. Basically when the group by is added I get no zero count records and I do need them. Help.